# Passing a Class vs passing an instance; Simple API design

Tags: java, generics, class-design

**Introduction**

I know the API/library I am about to describe is very simple, and it doesn't really matter what I do to get it working, but I hope to be eventually designing much more complex systems and would like to get some good practice in about how to design a simple and effective API.

**Information**

I am reworking a project in Android I did a while ago to make some of the code more reusable (Constantly experimenting with new 'API' designs for practice).

Part of this fairly simple app shuffles around text on the screen, and since there are three different programs based on this 'library' with their own shuffling effects, I chose to pull the common code out into an actual library and decouple the implementation of the shuffling from the rest of the system. I changed a few things to make this work: The code that handles the shuffling is put in a class, Each application provides a configuration object filled with the values needed to run the specific application. Under the current design, the configuration object provides the Class of the desired shuffle implementation. The library then creates an instance of the Class at a later time when it is needed.

I liked this because it lets my library control everything of the object and removed exposure of the instance to outside code, but it also prevents me from customizing the implementation with constructor parameters (speed of shuffle, direction, etc). (One solution to this is passing in an array of some sort that the implementation can pull it's data from when it is created by the library, but I hate libraries that require you to pass in parameters in some sort of cloudy and hard-to-check-at-compile-time config crap like "speed:90;herp:derp".)

**My Question**

Would it be best to pass the Class with the configuration so the library can control it's whole life-cycle, or is this impractical and I should just make a damn instance and pass it in. Also, if passing in a Class is impractical, when is passing in a Class a good idea? (Besides things like registering class instances under their Class in some sort of map for look-up later in some sort of plugin system)

Answer (score 0):

If you use DI (Dependency Injection), the life cycle of objects is handled external to the library. I prefer this approach unless the life cycle is very simple and there would be no need for the component to be configurable.

Comment: I am starting to feel that the lifecycle of things in Android is severely limiting my ability to implement 'normal' designs. And I thought providing a configuration object that eventually gets to the library with values/Types to use (the configuration is based on an interface) was Manually injected dependency (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection#Manually_injected_dependency). This also lets me change the configuration on the fly for interesting user end configuration options.